# Add a step in Y axis to increase chart height Chart JS

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have this Chart JS Bar chart [image]

Here the custom option used to render labels on top, but if the bar is exact size of max Y-axis value the label gets hidden or goes out of chart.
Is there any way to get the label outside of chart or increase Y-axis value?

Code:

```
 var barChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("third_party_chart"), {
          type: 'bar',
          data: response,
          options: {
            responsive: true,
            legend: {
              display: false,
            },
            "animation": {
              "duration": 1,
              "onComplete": function() {
                var chartInstance = this.chart,
                  ctx = chartInstance.ctx;

                ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
                ctx.textAlign = 'center';
                ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

                this.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset, i) {
                  var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
                  meta.data.forEach(function(bar, index) {
                    var data = dataset.data[index];

                    ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x, bar._model.y - 5);
                  });
                });
              }
            }
          }
        });
```

Comment: You can manually set the maximum value for each scale. The configuration depends on the Chart.js version you're using. You can refer to the [docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html). - See the [migration guide](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/getting-started/v3-migration/) for v3 - I'm not sure if it is `scales[id].ticks.max` or `suggestedMax`.

Comment: thanks @MoritzRoessler it helped alot :)